# RandomCutForest hyperparameter value limit is too small in Sagemaker

Tags: machine-learning, amazon-sagemaker

I'm trying to use RandomCutForest in Sagemaker with the data as below:

- Number of rows: 420000
- Feature dimension: 30

The problem is that RandomCutForest hyperparameters have the following restrictions (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/rcf_hyperparameters.html).

- num_samples_per_tree: min: 1, max: 2048
- num_trees: min: 50, max: 1000

I think RandomCutForest is not suitable for large dataset as described above because of that hyperparameter restrictions.
Even if you set the max values to those hyperparameters, 2048 num_samples_per_tree is too small in comparison with 420000-rows data.

I wonder why Sagemaker's RandomCutForest has such a restriction (due to performance issue, hardware capability or any other reason?), even though IsolationForest in sklearn has no such restrictions.
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.IsolationForest.html

If there's any workaround on this problem, please let me know.

Comment: How many anomalies do you have in your data set?

Answer (score 0):

Choosing an optimal value for `num_samples_per_tree` is dependent on your application and data set. This parameter is related to the expected density of anomalies that lie in your data set. Specifically, you should choose `num_samples_per_tree` such that 1/`num_samples_per_tree` roughly approximates the ratio of anomalous data points in your data. To illustrate this with an example, if 10 samples are used in each tree then you should expect that your data set contains an anomaly 1/10 of the time. Note that in most applications the range covered by the min and max value of this parameter should suffice to yield optimal performance of this algorithm.